# How to round the value to an integer from array elements with Query and MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

One of the fields contains an array with name ranges, each element of which can contain data in a decimal value. However, these fields can also be null. The array can be of any size. I need to round the value to an integer.

Example of `document` structure:

```
{
    "state" : {
        "aggregation" : {
            "ranges" : [ 
                {
                    "areaRange" : {
                        "range" : {
                            "from" : 11.54815694,
                            "to" : 22.09873028
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My java code:

```java
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("signalState.aggregation.ranges").exists(true).ne(null))
                .addCriteria(Criteria.where("state.aggregation.ranges.areaRange.range.from").exists(true).ne(null));

Update update = new Update().set(
    "state.aggregation.ranges.$.areaRange.range.from",
    ArithmeticOperators.Round.roundValueOf("state.aggregation.ranges.$.areaRange.range.from").place(1)
);

var result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, State.class);
log.info("Matched {}, Modified {}", result.getMatchedCount(), result.getModifiedCount());
```

But it does not work and throw the exception:

```
Write operation error on server localhost:52053. Write error: WriteError{code=52, message='The dollar ($) prefixed field '$round' in 'state.aggregation.ranges.0.areaRange.range.from.$round' is not valid for storage.', details={}}.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write operation error on server localhost:52053. Write error: WriteError{code=52, message='The dollar ($) prefixed field '$round' in 'state.aggregation.ranges.0.areaRange.range.from.$round' is not valid for storage.', details={}}.
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Write operation error on server localhost:52053. Write error: WriteError{code=52, message='The dollar ($) prefixed field '$round' in 'state.aggregation.ranges.0.areaRange.range.from.$round' is not valid for storage.', details={}}.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write operation error on server localhost:52053. Write error: WriteError{code=52, message='The dollar ($) prefixed field '$round' in 'state.aggregation.ranges.0.areaRange.range.from.$round' is not valid for storage.', details={}}.
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:117)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3044)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:600)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doUpdate(MongoTemplate.java:1735)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateMulti(MongoTemplate.java:1671)
```

Comment: You should use the pipelined form of updates. I am not much aware of MongoDB Java API, but you can see the native query here. https://mongoplayground.net/p/3lXZFy5hLy7